# Adobe After Effect 2020 on macOS shut off after launching

Tags: crash, adobe, after-effects

My question is I have installed and uninstslled many times Adobe After Effect variety versions (2020,2022,2023) I wanted to have latest version.

Now when I capitulated, with “most modern “cracked” version I told myself AF 2020 is good enough.

When I downloaded and installed AF 2020 17.0.1. from HaxNode and I tried to launch it, after showing initial picture app sudenlly shut off. I tried to find logs from app which are usualy located library/application support/adobe/ But I could’t see any log file assigned to Adobe After effects 2020 so I cannot check what is problem any why app crashing.

Do you have any ideas how could I fix this issue?

I have latest macOS MacBook pro 2020 m1 chip.

I have feeling since I have installed and uninstalled variety after effects cracked versions - and cracked versions are usualy (source code) modified.

Could this somehow ruin the app itself and previous files/folders  from versions 2020/2022/2023 that remained on my macOS interfere running the app property?

Is there any chance to run it, or only change is to reinstall whole macOS?

Thanks for any advices.

tried to find log files but isn’t there.